# Getting Length of Array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop

I'm currently working on a script in which I want to use an array length as a conditional argument. I can get the length of the array like this:

```
myarr=$(squeue | grep cjones903 | awk '{print $3}' )
echo ${#myarr}
```

but this wont work because I need the length to be evaluated iteratively in order to continue when the length drops below a threshold.

I would like to be able to do this:

```
while [ length is > x] do;
sleep 60;
else:
```

Comment: Array length is found by `${#arrayname[@]}` in bash. You can iterate over an array with `for ((i = 0; i < ${#arrayname[@]}; i++)); do ...`  (where `$i` = `0, 1, 2, ...`) or with `for i in "${arrayname[@]}"; do...` where (`$i` = `element1, element2, ...`) There  is no need for a conditional.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 
I can get the length of the array as in the first code snippet. I want to monitor the length of the output of 

     `(squeue | grep cjones903 | awk '{print $3}' )`

iteratively. After it drops below a certain count, I want to be able to continue my loop.

Comment: Oh, sorry, but the same still applies. check `${#myarray[@]} > x`. Now as written above, `myarr` is a string variable, not an array, so the length would simply be `${#myarr} > x`. To make `myarr` an array, you would need `myarr=( $(squeue | grep cjones903 | awk '{print $3}' ) )`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That will give me the length at the moment that I create the array, but it will not allow the length to be iteratively checked, right? Is it possible in bash?

Comment: Well, yes, and yes. Each time the conditional is checked with `${#myarr}` it will compute the length at that point. If you give a fuller example showing what you are trying to do, I can most likely show you how or give you a definitive on whether it is possible. Oh, also, your comparison should use the `-gt` or `-lt`, etc. numeric comparisons.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  I'm currently working on a SLURM controlled HPC cluster. I'm submitting a job and then monitoring how many of them are still running with the "squeue" command and grepping the output with my username. I want the script to idle with the sleep command until the the number of jobs drops below the threshold, and then I want to continue by submitting another job.

Comment: Alright, given that description, I'll do an example and you can draw from that. That helps firm up whether you were comparing a string length, a count, etc... If I understand, you get a number back from `squeeze ...` and you want to compare that number against some minimum threshold and sleep if below or submit if above. Give me a minute or two.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can't post too much of the squeue output so as to not compromise others personal info, but a single line looks like this:

`44297_0      normal lkvasurv cjones32  R       3:14      1 nid00807`

 I have several jobs running at once, they will each have a line like this. I'm counting my jobs by counting these lines. After my jobs have cleared ( I have a quota on the number of jobs I can run at once), I would like to add more jobs to the queue.

Comment: OK, that still leaves leave me scratching my head. Why not just check `squeue | grep cjones903 | wc -l` or something that returns a `number of jobs` running. Then just `while :; do; njobs=$(squeue | grep cjones903 | wc -l); while ((njobs > 10)); do sleep 120; njobs=$(squeue | grep cjones903 | wc -l); done; #submit new; done` Outer loop just runs forever, inner loop checks/sleeps, then when jobs fall below threshold submit new and repeat? You can also write num job to temp file and watch temp file with `inotifywait` and read/response as needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is actually very helpful. I guess I was trying another approach and got stuck in that way of thinking. I'm still learning basic bash. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since we seemed to have whittled it down in the comments to a way to check the number of jobs running by checking the number of lines returned by your `squeue` call, here is a little script I was tinkering with during the discussion. Take any further ideas you can from it. One thing to further look into is a *lock file* (or *lock dir*) to insure only one instance of the script runs at a time (many examples already on StackOverflow). Good luck:

```
#!/bin/bash

## consider setting lock file so only 1 instance runs
#  (many examples on SO)

## simple declarations
declare -i threshold=10             ## your limit, njobs above, sleep
declare -i njobs="$threshold"       ## threshold number of jobs limit
declare -i nseconds=60              ## seconds to sleep

while :; do     ## outer loop - runs perpetually

    njobs=$(squeue | grep cjones903 | wc -l)        ## get no. of jobs
    while ((njobs > threshold)); do                 ## test
        sleep "$nseconds"                           ## sleep if above
        njobs=$(squeue | grep cjones903 | wc -l)    ## get no. of jobs
    fi

    ## code to submit new batch of jobs here
    #  sleep a couple to let jobs distribute

done

exit 0
```